# Facebook redirect issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I am new to ruby on rails development. I am working on facebook login, it works fine. After logged in through facebook, it redirects to my url append with this #*=*. But i need to change the redirect path to my root path eg:http://localhost:3000/.

I am using the following code to login via facebook (Slim in Ruby on Rails )

= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) do

= image_tag 'facebook-signup.png', class: 'facebook-signup'

Please Advice me on this issue

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: set redirect url on facebook and ask questions with details

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, spend some time to ask a question.

What I understand is that you want to redirect to specific page after login.

just write this in ApplicationController

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    admin_root_path
end
```